# Order of vanishing of an integer polynomial at a point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients, and let $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2$ be a complex point. I want to show that $f$ cannot vanish at $\alpha$ to high order unless $\alpha$ is ``simple''. More precisely, suppose that

- f(x,y) vanishes to order at least $0.99\cdot \deg f$ at $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, and
- f(1,1)=1

> Does it imply existence of an integer polynomial $g(x,y)$ satisfying $g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=0$ and $g(1,1)=1$ that is *linear*, i.e., of degree $1$?

``Vanishing to order $m$'' at $\alpha$ means that all possible partial derivatives of order at most $m-1$ vanish at point $\alpha$.

Note that the single-variable version is a simple consequence of [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29).

I previously asked an [analogous question over $\mathbb{C}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/209720/806), but the answer turned out to be contrary to what I expected. This is the original question that I am interested in.

I do not know how to answer this question even if one replaces $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$ throughout.

Comment: In the one-variable case, the condition that $f(\alpha)$ vanishes implies that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. In your situation you're only assuming that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb Q$. If you're willing to assume that they are both algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, it might be easier to prove what you want. Or do you really need to allow the $\alpha_i$'s to be transcendental?

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but there is a general way involving multiplier ideals to do something like this. Suppose that there is a polynomial of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P ^n$ vanishing at points $Z=\{z_1,\ldots , z_m\}$, then there is a polynomial of degree $\leq nd/k-1$ (see A on page 76 of the paper by Esnault-Viehweg http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/users/esnault/preprints/ec/minoration.pdf). For $n=2$ (this case is due to Chudnoski) and $k=.99d$ this bound is $[2/.99-1]=2$. So for vanishing $\geq deg f$ it would have worked. There may be way around this using LTC's. If important I can look into it.

Comment: Likely I am missing something, but are you asking for which $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ exists linear g(x,y) with the desired properties? This appears system of linear equations in two variables.

Comment: Isn't $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=1,f(x,y)=1/2\,{x}^{2}-1/2\,{y}^{2}-x+y$ counterexample?

Comment: @JoeSilverman The case of transcendental $\alpha_i$'s is actually the easier case. Indeed, then the ideal of polynomial relations that $\alpha_i$'s satisfy is principal, say $I=(h)$, and $f$ vanishes to order $m$ iff $f$ is divisible by $h^m$.

Comment: @Hacon Thanks for the reference! However, it is all over $\mathbb{C}$. Is there a version over $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @joro No, it is not a counterexample since I require $f(\alpha)=0$ and $f(1,1)=0$. If $\alpha=(1,1)$, these are incompatible.

Comment: @BorisBukh Thanks. Do you have typo -- you need f(1,1)=1, which I missed. Does the buggy counterexample has enough order?

Comment: @joro Yes, f(1,1)=1.

Comment: @BorisBukh Is the order of vanishing in the buggy counterexample high enough?

Comment: @BorisBukh As you say my comment is over $\mathbb C$. However, the kind of game you play with multiplier ideal sheaves could produce a curve which is invariant under $Aut{\mathbb C)$ and hence defined over $\mathbb Q$. Unluckily I couldn't get anything useful from this.

Comment: What about $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=2, f=-x^2+2*y^2+4*x-8*y+4$? f(1,1)=1 and $f(2,2)=f_x(2,2)=f_y(2,2)=0$. There are no solutions to $2x+2y=0,x+y=1$.

Comment: @joro You are right. I feel that this is an indication that I did not ask the right question. Probably I should go back, and think what question I really should have asked.

Comment: I think my second example is flawed too. Don't take into account the free coefficient of $g$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this question appeared in Section 4 of [my paper on the ranks of matrices with few distinct entries](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00145). The solution borrows an idea from the Dracula's answer. Please upvote his answer. Below is a sketch of the solution.

**Step 1)**
Let $V$ be the set of points where $f$ vanishes to order greater than $\tfrac{2}{3}\deg f$. If $l$ is any secant of $V$, then $f$ vanishes to the order exceeding $\tfrac{1}{3}\deg f$ on each point of $l$. Hence, $f$ vanishes to the order $\mathord{\geq} \tfrac{1}{3}\deg f$ on the secant variety $\operatorname{Sec}_1(V)$. Similarly $f$ vanishes on any line passing through a point of $V$ and a point of $\operatorname{Sec}_1(V)$. So, $f$ vanishes on the $2$'nd secant variety $\operatorname{Sec}_2(V)$. It is clear that $\operatorname{Sec}_2(V)$ is an affine subspace defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Step 2)** If there is no linear polynomial $g$ that vanishes on $\operatorname{Sec}_2(V)$ and satisfies $g(1,1)=1$, then in fact there is a rational point $v\in \operatorname{Sec}_2(V)$ for which no such polynomial vanishing at $v$ exists. This is proved by using a theorem of van der Waerden characterizing when a system of linear equations in integers admits no solution.

**Step 3)** One then shows that there is no integer polynomial $g$ satisfying $g(1,1)=1$ vanishing at $v\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ if and only if $v\equiv (1,1)\pmod p$ for some prime $p$. In that case, however, $f(v)\equiv f(1,1)\equiv 1 \pmod p$, contradicting the fact that $f$ vanishes on $\operatorname{Sec}_2(V)$.

**Furthermore** The bound $\tfrac{2}{3}\deg f$ is sharp. Given a cubic Galois extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$, one can find three points $p_1,p_2,p_3\in F^2$ and three linear polynomials $f_1,f_2,f_3$ with the following properties:

- The points $p_1,p_2,p_3$ are Galois conjugates of one another,
- The linear polynomials $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are Galois conjugates of one another,
- The linear polynomial $f_1$ vanishes on the line $p_2p_3$, the $f_2$ vanishes on $p_1p_3$, and $f_3$ --- on $p_1p_2$,
- The coefficients of $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are algebraic integers, and $f_1(1,1)=f_2(1,1)=f_3(1,1)=1$.

Then the polynomial $f=f_1f_2f_3$ has integer coefficients, and vanishes to order $2$ at each of $p_1,p_2,p_3$. It also satisfies $f(1,1)=1$. However, no integer linear polynomial $g$ vanishes at $p_1$, say.

A concrete example that one obtains using the splitting field of $x^3-3x+1$ consists of the polynomial $f(x,y)=x^3+3 x^2 y-6 x^2-3 x y+3 x-y^3+3 y+1$ and points $p_i=(\rho_i^2-2,3-\rho_i^2-\rho_i)$ where $\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3$ are the roots of $x^3-3x+1$.

Answer (score 3):

Over $\mathbf{Q}$ you can argue as follows.

Case I. $a$ is the unique point where $f$ vanishes to high order. Then $a$ is invariant under $\text{Aut}(\mathbf{C})$ and hence defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ and hence there is a line defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ passing through $a$.

Case II. There are exactly $2$ points $a, b$ where $f$ vanishes to high order. Then the line $ab$ is defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.

Case III. There are finitely many $> 2$ points where $f$ vanishes to high degree. This is impossible because then every conic passing through these points must be contained in $f = 0$. (Use Bezout.)

Case IV. There is an infinite nr of points where $f$ vanishes to high degree. The locus of these points has to be an algebraic curve $g = 0$ and $g$ has to have degee $1$ because a high power of $g$ divides $f$.

Since $\mathbf{Z} \subset \mathbf{Q}$ this also proves something over $\mathbf{Z}$ and with a variant of Gauss's lemma you can get a suitable statement, but I haven't thought it through. Maybe Case I is the most interesting one from this point of view.

Comment: This is very nice and helpful! This shows a direction to get what I want.

Comment: How should I acknowledge this answer in a paper? You can e-mail me, or otherwise I can refer to you by the penname "Dracula".